# CSS file with two #

Tags: html, css, nav

I read an article with some css file

```css
#mainNav #toTop a {
    float: right;
    margin: 0 8px 0 0;
    font-size: 40px;
}
```

Can someone explain why they have two `#` things in one css id type ? and how can I use it?

Thank you in advance

Comment: `a` That is a child of `#toTop` that is a child of `#mainNav`.

Comment: Are you able to reference the article? Are you sure there isn't a comma between #mainNav and #toTop?

Comment: Here's how that would look in the HTML: http://jsfiddle.net/6NNEn/

Comment: @F4r-20: for the records, it is: `a` that is a descendant of `#toTop` that is a descendant of `#mainNav`. Meaning that they can be connected by more than one level of nesting. `_` (space) is Descendant Combinator (http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#descendant-combinators), while `>` is Child Combinator (http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#child-combinators)

Comment: @AndreaLigios A good point, but you know where I was coming from ;)

Comment: @F4r-20 from a partially correct definition ? :>

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know what you mean by a "CSS id type". So I'm just going to explain CSS in general, and we'll see if what this snippet is doing becomes clear.

In CSS you have selectors and property blocks. Your question is about a selector:

```
#mainNav #toTop a
```

Selectors are used to target (and on some other platforms to query) HTML (and sometimes XML) elements. This particular rule is using three simple selectors - two id selectors and a tag name selector - put together with two descendant combinators.

That means the selector will target (and the rule block accompanying it will affect) any anchor element (`<a>`) which is the descendant of any element with `id=toTop` which in turn is the descendant of any element with `id=mainNav`.

Since id elements are supposed to be unique, it might seem silly to have two of them in one selector. You can do it if you want to though, and sometimes you'll need to: we haven't spoken about selector specificity.

Specificity defines which rules take precedence over other rules. For example, if two elements both seem to target the same element:

```
form .label { color: blue; }
#contact-us .label { color: green; }
/* what color is the label? */
```

... then which rule takes precedence? To figure that out we calculate the specificity. I won't explain the math.

So, let's suppose you have a CSS stylesheet in your project which you can't change - it comes from a 3rd party vendor or something, and it looks like this:

```
#toTop a { /*...*/ }
```

If you needed to change the styling of the elements affected by that rule, what would you do?

You could (and probably would) define a new rule with greater specificity. One of the ways you can do that is by adding another id selector to your rule:

```
#mainNav #toTop a { /*...*/ }
```

But realistically you could just as easily add any other selector:

```
div#toTop a { /*...*/ }
```

Realistically whether it's necessary or not depends on what you're trying to do, what other rules it's interacting with, and what kind of HTML you're dealing with.

---

Here's another thing to consider: CSS stylesheets are meant to be re-used. What if that element should behave differently if it is in a different place in the document? What if the `id="toTop"` is sometimes inside the `id="mainNav"` element on some pages, and in a different place (let's say in the `id="footer"` element) on others? What if it moves, depending on client-side JavaScript? Then you might want to define CSS like this:

```
#mainNav #toTop a { /*...*/ }
#footer #toTop a { /*...*/ }
```

... so ultimately again, why a developer would choose to do this really depends on the CSS, JavaScript and HTML they are working with. It's definitely unusual, but it's not unnecessary nor bad practice.

Comment: Good example regarding #mainNav and #footer - these types of constructions are quite common in content management systems and it is good to be able to deal with the CSS specificity issues.

Answer (score 1):

ID must always be unique. However it is valid to use more than one id to make styles more specific.

In your example you are looking for an element with id #toTop inside #mainNav.

Answer (score 1):

This is a perfectly valid CSS rule.  It is very specific.  The motivation for this use may have to do with how the page layout is designed and/or how JavaScript handlers interact with the DOM.

Answer (score 1):

This is an example of poor CSS. The selector hierarchy in your example is redundant and unnecessary. It says select all `a` elements that are descendants of the element with the ID of `toTop` that is a descendant of the element with the ID of `mainNav`. So it assumes a basic structure like this:

```
<div id="mainNav">
    <div id="toTop">
        <a href="#">link</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

However, as **IDs must be unique**, only this is needed to target the same elements:

```
#toTop a
```

Comment: for the records, it is: `a` that is a descendant of `#toTop` that is a descendant of `#mainNav`. Meaning that they can be connected by more than one level of nesting. `_` (space) is Descendant Combinator (w3.org/TR/selectors/#descendant-combinators), while `>` is Child Combinator (w3.org/TR/selectors/#child-combinators)

Comment: The downvote is mine; I don't feel that this is necessarily an example of poor CSS, nor necessarily redundant. It depends on the nature of the document (or documents) the CSS is being used with. It might be poor CSS and it might be redundant but I feel like this answer jumps the gun in coming to that conclusion, without considering that CSS can be re-used across different documents and that CSS rules sometimes need to take precedence over other rules using specificity - and adding an `#id` is one of the ways to do that.

Answer (score 1):

`#mainNav #toTop a` is using the [Descendant Combinator](http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#descendant-combinators) to specify an element `a` descendant of an element with id `toTop` descendant of an element with id `mainNav`.

As said by other answers, this rule seems to be overly specific, because `ID`s must be uniques and then `#toTop a` should do the trick.

The real reason behind the choice of declaring this rule is:

> Assuming that in a website you have one or more *shared* CSS (read:
>   you don't have an different CSS for every page), this rule means:
>
> - in a page where `a` is descendant of `#toTop`, but `#toTop` is descendant of an `#mainNav` element too, then apply this rule;
> - in a page where `a` is descendant of `#toTop`, but `#toTop` is NOT descendant of an `#mainNav` element, then DO NOT apply this rule;

because `#toTop` could be an reusable element that could be declared in different places (one-per-page, of course), for example inside the `#mainNav` in a page, and inside the `#sideNav` in another page, with a desired potentially different behavior and look-and-feel.

Comment: Is that a quote? Do you have a citation?

Comment: Nah, is just `creative formatting`, for a better readability ;) What about the content..? :)

Comment: Uhm, didn't noticed that in last part of your answer you said the same things, I'd upvoted you without reading it all :X

Comment: Well you were more concise ;) +1